# get_posts with ajax return nothing

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress

I'm trying to get a post by using `get_posts` with slug which received successfully from ajax. However, it returns nothing. Please point out my mistake.

My ajax:

```
var nextt = document.getElementById("nextt");
nextt.addEventListener("click",function(e){
    event.preventDefault();
    var nextpage = document.querySelector("a[rel=next]").getAttribute("href");
    xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open('POST', ajaxurl, true);
    xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded;');
    xhr.onreadystatechange  = function(){
        var content = document.getElementById('main');
        if(xhr.readyState  == 4){
            if(xhr.status  == 200) {
                content.innerHTML = xhr.responseText;
            } else{
                content.innerHTML = 'Cannot connect to server. Check your internet connection '}
        }
    };
    xhr.send('action=load_selanjutnya&nonce=' + ajaxnonce + '&value=' + nextpage);
},false);
```

On my function.php

```
function nextpage(){
   global $post;
    print_r($_REQUEST);
    $slug = $_REQUEST['value'];
    $args=array(
        'name' => $slug,
        'post_type' => 'post',
        'post_status' => 'publish',
        'numberposts' => 1
    );
    $my_posts = get_posts( $args );
    if( $my_posts ) {
        foreach ($my_posts as $post)
            setup_postdata( $post );
            get_template_part( 'single-ajax', get_post_format() );
        wp_reset_postdata();
    }
    else {echo $slug . ' - Fail. '; var_dump($my_posts);}
    exit();
}
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nextpage', 'nextpage' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_nextpage', 'nextpage' );
```

I expect it to load the content page instead of nothing/blank as return.

Comment: What happens when you call your endpoint directly from browser (or even better from Postman or similar app)? Do you get some response or not. I'm aiming to find out where the issue is: in php endpoint or in JS.

Comment: Yes, I got the response what I looking for (value = nextpage, is a slug: https://domain.name/booktitle/page-2/), just on get_posts doesn't return anything with the slug sent by ajax.

Comment: '&value=' + nextpage); at xhr.send, the end of js code.

Comment: yes. you are correct

Comment: maybe you need to set additional headers. Are the headers identical to those in the requests that work?

Comment: I don't know what should I use other than the current, here the result of ajax: https://imgur.com/EvxZIHO

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, this issue fixed. The problem is slug itself, it had "https://domainname/path" should be only pathname, a basic issue that makes me so confused.

```
$slug = parse_url($_REQUEST['value'], PHP_URL_PATH);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just to be sure... did you initialize Ajax to be used in your wordpress theme ?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var ajaxurl = "<?php echo admin_url('admin-ajax.php'); ?>";
</script>
```

should be present in your  section.

Comment: yes, already.  var ajaxurl = <?php echo json_encode( admin_url( "admin-ajax.php" ) ); ?>;      
    var ajaxnonce = <?php echo json_encode( wp_create_nonce( "itr_ajax_nonce" ) ); ?>;